# coordinates function sometimes not working

Tags: php, function, maps, coordinates

I'm using this function to get the coordinates of any address:

```
function getCoordinates($address) {
    $address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address); // replace all the white space with "+" sign to match with google search pattern
    $address = str_replace("-", "+", $address); // replace all the "-"  with "+" sign to match with google search pattern
    $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address";
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($response,TRUE); //generate array object from the response from the web
    return ($json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'].",".$json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']);
}
```

Sometimes it works and sometimes it only gets "," for the same address.

Do I need to use another function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps - converting address to latitude & longitude - PHP backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595830/google-maps-converting-address-to-latitude-longitude-php-backend)

Comment: Did you try to log your $address in your function ? So you could understand where exactly your value turn to ",".

Answer (score 0):

try this

$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$address;

Comment: No it's the same results again